# Css style which show <a> as button

Tags: html, css

I have Css style for `<a>` given below:

```
a {
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    background: #4479BA; 
    color: #FFF;
}
```

And I want to show this like as button style. I have seen many css but I want only default button css.

Can someone please suggest me a way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You can change your anchor to a button element, but it will no longer serve as an anchor.. The different OS's also style buttons in different ways, so if you style it like a Mac button, Windows users will not see a relevant button.

Comment: @user1656416, add also `display: inline-block` as `a` is an inline type element.

Comment: http://hellohappy.org/css3-buttons/ and http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use;

```
a{
  appearance: button; /* CSS3 */    
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-appearance: button; /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: button; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-appearance: button; /* Opera */
  cursor: default;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/suw8R/5/)*** is a Live Demo

This is a CSS3 property. Refer the table below;

[image: Table]

If you want a CSS button, that look exactly like a button, not using CSS3, it is somewhat hard to acheive :( . But you may refer the tutorial **[How to make sexy buttons with CSS](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html)**. But if you want the exact look of default HTML button, well, you may use an image which looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a heref="#">A tag button</a>​

a{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #6b6b6b 0%,
        #000000);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#6b6b6b),
        to(#000000));
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(115,110,115,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(115,110,115,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(115,110,115,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.4),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/k7xLn/

Here is the best tool to generate css for button http://css3button.net/

Comment: OP need default button styling.

Comment: You can style like default by using diff colors

Comment: See the demo in my answer or in blasteralfred's answer for default button view.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following CSS for the anchors:

```
a {
     appearance:button; /* For Good Browsers */
     -moz-appearance:button; /* For Firefox */
     -webkit-appearance:button; /* For Safari and Chrome */

     padding: 5px 15px; 
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
}​
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/zFnXn/)